# How can I create a key value input type for a product attribute?

Tags: attributes, magento2.2

I'm trying to get a table on a product page that exists of **2 columns**. I want to use this to display technical details about that product. The first column would have a value like: 'volume' and then the column next to it would have '1 litre'.

I've tried to just use a normal text field and wysiwyg editor but i'd like something more structured.

[image: idealy it'd look something like this with an button "add" to add another key value pair]

I'm used to working with Drupal where this can be done with paragrahs or a custom field type. 
But I'm wondering if there is a way to do this or something similar in Magento?

Actually today I've noticed the theme Magento marketplace is exactly what i want. [image: this is how they list technical specifications]

Does anyone know if they made this by just using Magento? Also is it maybe downloadable somewhere?